# Why does some nodes have a x and y position and others not

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to understand the coordinate system of JavaFX.

For some nodes (shapes?) like `Line` or `Rectangle` I can (or should) specify a x and y value in the coordinate system.

What exactly is this? Is this a translation and stretch which is later appended to the node or something else? Other nodes only have a `setLayoutX()` method, whereas e.g. the `Line` has both `setLayoutX()` as well as `setStartX()`.

Thanks!

Comment: What do the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/) say?

Answer (score 6):

Every `Node` has two different bounds properties (ignoring [`Node#layoutBounds`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#layoutBoundsProperty)) relating to two different coordinate spaces—local and parent.

1. [`Node#boundsInLocal`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#boundsInLocalProperty)

   > The rectangular bounds of this `Node` in the node's untransformed local coordinate space. For nodes that extend `Shape`, the local bounds will also include space required for a non-zero stroke that may fall outside the shape's geometry that is defined by position and size attributes. The local bounds will also include any clipping set with `clip` as well as effects set with `effect`.
   >
   > [...]
2. [`Node#boundsInParent`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#boundsInParentProperty)

   > The rectangular bounds of this `Node` which include its transforms. `boundsInParent` is calculated by taking the local bounds (defined by `boundsInLocal`) and applying the transform created by setting the following additional variables
   >
   > 1. `transforms` ObservableList
   > 2. `scaleX`, `scaleY`, `scaleZ`
   > 3. `rotate`
   > 4. `layoutX`, `layoutY`
   > 5. `translateX`, `translateY`, `translateZ`
   >
   > The resulting bounds will be conceptually in the coordinate space of the `Node`'s parent, however the node need not have a parent to calculate these bounds.
   >
   > [...]

This means properties such as `layoutX` and `translateX` only affect the *bounds-in-parent*. Basically, the *bounds-in-parent* is simply the *bounds-in-local* with the various transformations applied. But when it comes to the "special" `Shape` properties, such as the `x` and `y` properties of `Rectangle`, they directly affect the *bounds-in-local*. I was unable to find documentation explaining this, though maybe I just missed it or this behavior is supposed to be obvious to those "in the know". Unfortunately I won't be able to explain to you *why* these `Shape` properties affect the *bounds-in-local* directly as I lack foundational knowledge in this area.

That said, I can visually demonstrate the differences regarding *bounds-in-local* with the following example:

**App.java**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        var root = FXMLLoader.<Parent>load(getClass().getResource("App.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

**Controller.java**

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private void handleMousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
        event.consume();

        var source = (Node) event.getSource();
        source.setUserData(source.localToParent(event.getX(), event.getY()));
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleMouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
        event.consume();

        var source = (Node) event.getSource();
        var lastPoint = (Point2D) source.getUserData();
        var nextPoint = source.localToParent(event.getX(), event.getY());

        source.setTranslateX(source.getTranslateX() + nextPoint.getX() - lastPoint.getX());
        source.setTranslateY(source.getTranslateY() + nextPoint.getY() - lastPoint.getY());

        source.setUserData(nextPoint);
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleMouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
        event.consume();

        var source = (Node) event.getSource();
        if (source instanceof Rectangle) {
            var rectangle = (Rectangle) source;
            rectangle.setX(rectangle.getX() + rectangle.getTranslateX());
            rectangle.setTranslateX(0);
            rectangle.setY(rectangle.getY() + rectangle.getTranslateY());
            rectangle.setTranslateY(0);
        }
        source.setUserData(null);
    }

}
```

**App.fxml**

```xml
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Separator?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Region?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.Color?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<HBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/12.0.2" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Controller"
      prefWidth="1000" prefHeight="600" spacing="15">

    <fx:define>
        <Font fx:id="titleFont" name="Impact" size="24"/>
        <Color fx:id="inLocalColor" fx:value="LIME"/>
        <Color fx:id="inParentColor" fx:value="RED"/>
    </fx:define>

    <padding>
        <Insets topRightBottomLeft="25"/>
    </padding>

    <VBox HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" spacing="10" alignment="CENTER">
        <Label text="SHAPE" font="$titleFont"/>
        <Separator/>
        <Pane fx:id="shapePane" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
            <clip>
                <Rectangle x="-5" y="-5" width="${shapePane.width}" height="${shapePane.height}"/>
            </clip>
            <Pane managed="false">
                <Rectangle fx:id="shape" width="100" height="100" managed="false" onMousePressed="#handleMousePressed"
                           onMouseDragged="#handleMouseDragged" onMouseReleased="#handleMouseReleased"/>
                <Rectangle fill="TRANSPARENT" stroke="$inLocalColor" strokeType="INSIDE" strokeWidth="2"
                           mouseTransparent="true" x="${shape.boundsInLocal.minX}" y="${shape.boundsInLocal.minY}"
                           width="${shape.boundsInLocal.width}" height="${shape.boundsInLocal.height}"/>
                <Rectangle fill="TRANSPARENT" stroke="$inParentColor" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="2"
                           mouseTransparent="true" x="${shape.boundsInParent.minX}" y="${shape.boundsInParent.minY}"
                           width="${shape.boundsInParent.width}" height="${shape.boundsInParent.height}"/>
            </Pane>
        </Pane>
    </VBox>

    <Separator orientation="VERTICAL"/>

    <VBox HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" spacing="10" alignment="CENTER">
        <Label text="NON-SHAPE" font="$titleFont"/>
        <Separator/>
        <Pane fx:id="nonShapePane" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
            <clip>
                <Rectangle x="-5" y="-5" width="${nonShapePane.width}" height="${nonShapePane.height}"/>
            </clip>
            <Pane managed="false">
                <Region fx:id="nonShape" prefWidth="100" prefHeight="100" style="-fx-background-color: black;"
                        onMousePressed="#handleMousePressed" onMouseDragged="#handleMouseDragged"
                        onMouseReleased="#handleMouseReleased"/>
                <Rectangle fill="TRANSPARENT" stroke="$inLocalColor" strokeType="INSIDE" strokeWidth="2"
                           mouseTransparent="true" x="${nonShape.boundsInLocal.minX}" y="${nonShape.boundsInLocal.minY}"
                           width="${nonShape.boundsInLocal.width}" height="${nonShape.boundsInLocal.height}"/>
                <Rectangle fill="TRANSPARENT" stroke="$inParentColor" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="2"
                           mouseTransparent="true" x="${nonShape.boundsInParent.minX}"
                           y="${nonShape.boundsInParent.minY}" width="${nonShape.boundsInParent.width}"
                           height="${nonShape.boundsInParent.height}"/>
            </Pane>
        </Pane>
    </VBox>
</HBox>
```

Running the above results in:

[image: GIF of example application]

The red outlines are the *bounds-in-parent* of the node while the green outlines are the *bounds-in-local* of the node. When dragging the node the position is updated via the `translate[X|Y]` properties, for both the shape and non-shape, which don't affect the *bounds-in-local*. But for the shape, when the mouse is released the translate transforms are copied over to the "shape properties" (i.e. `Rectangle.x` and `Rectangle.y`) and then the translate properties are reset to `0`. This shows how, for a shape, the *bounds-in-local* may have a different origin point than `(0,0)`.

The fact a `Shape` changes its *bounds-in-local* has consequences for things such as transforms. For example, if you want to rotate a node about its center using a `Rotate`, then the pivot point would be different for a shape than a non-shape:

- Shape (e.g. `Rectangle`): `(x + width / 2, y + height / 2)`<sup>1</sup>
- Non-shape (e.g. `Region`): `(width / 2, height / 2)`<sup>2</sup>

Another thing affected is the local mouse coordinates you get from a `MouseEvent`.

---

<sup>1. Note for shapes like `Circle` you can simply use `centerX` and `centerY`. An interesting consequence of this for `Circle` is that the *bounds-in-local* will have a negative min values.</sup>
<sup>2. Technically the only difference here is that `x` and `y` are known to be `0`.</sup>

Comment: Good explanation. This may explain a problem I was having with a Tetris game I tried creating. After I would rotate a piece, the piece would go beyond the bounds. I will have to look it over again now that I have this info.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. This was exactly what I was missing from the Javadoc and could not find for myself. I will try to implement this and accept your answer.

Comment: I wrote a [similar sample app for demonstrating layout bounds](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1441960), you could also take a look at that if you are interested.