# How to center text without using any layout?

Tags: java, javafx, layout, position, text-alignment

```
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment;
import javafx.scene.text.TextBoundsType;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HorizontalTextAlignment extends javafx.application.Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        var rectangle = new Rectangle(600, 100, Color.TURQUOISE);
        var text = new Text(rectangle.getWidth() / 2, rectangle.getHeight() / 2, "TEXT");
        text.setBoundsType(TextBoundsType.VISUAL);
        text.setFont(new Font(100));
        text.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
        text.setTextOrigin(VPos.CENTER);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(new Pane(rectangle, text)));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

I would need to center the text without using any layout. As you may notice, while vertical alignment works, horizontal doesn't. Of course, this could be solved by a simple calculation.

```
// You need to change the horizontal position of the text for this to work.
var text = new Text(rectangle.getLayoutX(), rectangle.getHeight() / 2, "TEXT");
...
var rectangleWidth = rectangle.getWidth();
var textWidth = text.getLayoutBounds().getWidth();
text.setLayoutX((rectangleWidth - textWidth) / 2);
```

[image]

The problem is, although it's not easy to see in the picture that it's not exactly in the middle.

This is good to see if you only change the initialization.

```
var text = new Text(rectangle.getLayoutX(), rectangle.getHeight() / 2, "TEXT");
```

[image]

However, this cannot be solved by simply subtracting the desired value (in this case -2) from the horizontal position, because when I change the text.

[image]

It is necessary to subtract 9. And that is the problem. I can never know in advance how much must be deducted from the horizontal position.

How do I solve this, please?

Thank you

Comment: Are you allowed to use a [Label](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Label.html)?

Comment: Oh, I didn't think of that. Of course yes. However, will it help or will the result be the same? I'm not sure.

Comment: Since a Label has a text alignment property, I expect you will still have to do some work.  I would try binding the Label’s minimum width to the containing Pane’s width.

Comment: Use layout managers. Your teachers are not presenting the material right if you are doing without.

Comment: I don’t think your requirements here make sense. Centering something is, by definition, “layout”. The supported ways to lay things out in JavaFX are to use some kind of `Pane` (which you’re doing): either use an existing `Pane` subclass, or write your own subclass of `Parent` (or `Region` or `Pane`) and override the appropriate methods (most importantly `layoutChildren()`). But really a `Label` seems to have the functionality you need.

Comment: @VGR You mean the `alignment` property, not the `textAlignment` property, since this appears only to be single-line text.

Comment: This is a bit of a guess, but I think the unpredictable horizontal offset is because of the font you are using. This looks like a mono spaced font, which means that each glyph takes up the same amount of horizontal space. It looks like this particular font achieves that by allowing a little invisible space around some of the naturally-smaller glyphs. Hence the horizontal offset is just the invisible space within the first glyph. Just a guess, but that’s what it looks like to me. (If I’m right, “I” will create a bigger gap than, e.g. “M” when used as the first character.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could all be accomplished much more easily by using a `StackPane` (e.g. as shown in [@Oboe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62604299/6395627)). Using the appropriate layout should always be your first choice. However, the rest of my answer shows how to do it manually.

---

The `x` and `y` properties define the *origin point* of the text node. The x-coordinate determines where the left side of the text starts. However, the y-coordinate can be customized somewhat via the `textOrigin` property.

```
                   X (always)
                   |
Y (VPos.TOP)-------╔════════════════════════════════╗
                   ║                                ║
Y (VPos.CENTER)----║          Text Node             ║
                   ║                                ║
Y (VPos.BOTTOM)----╚════════════════════════════════╝
```

<sup>*Note: There's also `VPos.BASELINE` (the default) but I don't know how to visualize that.*</sup>

As you can see, when you set the `x` property to `rectangle.getWidth() / 2` you are aligning the *left side* of the text node with the horizontal center of the rectangle. If you want to align the horizontal center of the text node with the horizontal center of the rectangle you have to take the width of the text node into account. Here's an example:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment;
import javafx.scene.text.TextBoundsType;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {
    var rectangle = new Rectangle(600, 100, Color.TURQUOISE);

    var text = new Text("TEXT");
    text.setBoundsType(TextBoundsType.VISUAL);
    text.setFont(new Font(100));
    text.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
    text.setTextOrigin(VPos.CENTER);

    // WARNING: Assumes Rectangle is at (0, 0)
    text.setX(rectangle.getWidth() / 2 - text.getLayoutBounds().getWidth() / 2);
    text.setY(rectangle.getHeight() / 2);

    stage.setScene(new Scene(new Pane(rectangle, text)));
    stage.show();
  }
}
```

Notice that I set the `x` property after setting everything else (e.g. font, text, etc.). That's necessary for the resulting text's width to be known. Of course, this is not responsive; if the the dimensions of the rectangle or text change you have to manually recompute the new `x` value. The ideal solution, when we ignore layouts, is to use a bindings. Something like:

```java
// WARNING: Assumes Rectangle is at (0, 0)
text.xProperty()
    .bind(
        Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
            () -> rectangle.getWidth() / 2 - text.getLayoutBounds().getWidth() / 2,
            rectangle.widthProperty(),
            text.layoutBoundsProperty()));
```

Unfortunately, changing the `x` property changes the layout bounds of the text and the above leads to a `StackOverflowError`. The same is true of the text's bounds-in-local ([this is a characteristic of shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57761697/6395627)). There is a solution though if you don't mind positioning the text via its `layoutX` and `layoutY` properties:

```java
// WARNING: Assumes Rectangle is at (0, 0)

// leave text.x = 0 and text.y = 0
text.layoutXProperty()
    .bind(
        Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
            () -> rectangle.getWidth() / 2 - text.getLayoutBounds().getWidth() / 2,
            rectangle.widthProperty(),
            text.layoutBoundsProperty()));
// assumes textOrigin = VPos.CENTER
text.layoutYProperty().bind(rectangle.heightProperty().divide(2));
```

Note the `layoutX` and `layoutY` properties come from `Node`. They're used by layouts to position their children. But since you're not using a layout which automatically positions its children you can safely set them manually. There's also the `translateX` and `translateY` properties. These add onto the layout properties. For example, [ignoring other things](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#getTransforms()), the final x-position will be `layoutX + translateX` (similar for the final y-position); for a `Text` node the final x-position would be `x + layoutX + translateX` (again, similar for the final y-position).

You may have noticed that all my examples warn about assuming the rectangle is at the origin of its parent. To fix that issue you simply have to add the rectangles x and y positions to the text's layout position.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Is perfect. Of course, this can only be used for position (0,0), otherwise it must be adjusted. Therefore, I would just like to add that if the position is eg (100,100), for LayoutX it is enough to add 100 - `text.layoutXProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> 100 + ...` and LayoutY must be rewritten in a similar form as LayoutX - `text.layoutYProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> 100 + rectangle.getHeight() / 2, rectangle.heightProperty(), text.layoutBoundsProperty()));`

Comment: Hello, I have one more question. The point is that I wanted to use the code again, but this time align the text to [0,0] and I can't get rid of this strange indentation, as I illustrated in the picture in the question. How do I adjust this, please, to make it work? Thank you

Comment: Maybe try messing around with the [bounds type](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/text/Text.html#boundsTypeProperty)?

Answer (score 1):

If are not forced to use those specific `Node`s, I would use `Label` instead of `Text` and `StackPane` instead of `Pane`:

```
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(600, 100, Color.TURQUOISE);

Label label = new Label("TEXT");
label.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
label.setFont(new Font(100));

StackPane.setAlignment(label, Pos.CENTER);
StackPane.setAlignment(rectangle, Pos.CENTER);

StackPane pane = new StackPane(rectangle, label);

pane.prefWidthProperty().bind(rectangle.widthProperty());
pane.prefHeightProperty().bind(rectangle.heightProperty());

stage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
stage.show();
```

**Update**

Given that you cannot use StackPane, here is a solution completely out of the box.

You can create a new `Shape` subtracting the `Text` from a `Rectangle`. Then you will have two `Rectangle`s, one with the text transparent and another one for the background (that will give color to the text).

The benefit of these approach is that you end with two `Shapes` with the same bounds and will be easier to layout in the `Scene`.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment;
import javafx.scene.text.TextBoundsType;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(600, 100);

        Text text = new Text("TEXT");

        text.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
        text.setBoundsType(TextBoundsType.VISUAL);
        text.setFont(new Font(100));
        text.setTextOrigin(VPos.CENTER);

        text.setX(rectangle.getWidth() / 2 - text.getLayoutBounds().getWidth() / 2);
        text.setY(rectangle.getHeight() / 2);

        Shape shape = Shape.subtract(rectangle, text);

        shape.setFill(Color.TURQUOISE);

        shape.layoutXProperty().bind(rectangle.layoutXProperty());
        shape.layoutYProperty().bind(rectangle.layoutYProperty());
        shape.translateXProperty().bind(rectangle.translateXProperty());
        shape.translateYProperty().bind(rectangle.translateYProperty());

        stage.setScene(new Scene(new Pane(rectangle, shape)));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's what I wanted to avoid. As I wrote in the title of the question, I didn't want to use any layout. Of course, I have to use Pane, which I always use, but I wanted to achieve it without using StackPane, etc. This is just an example for simplicity.

Comment: @yoda666, in that case I would suggest a solution completely out of the box. You can create a new `Shape` subtracting the `Text` from a `Rectangle`. Then you will have 2 `Rectangle`s, one with the text transparent and another one for the background (that will give color to the text). I updated the answer to include this approach.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand why you're using the `Shape`? When (in your code) I change `Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(600, 100);` for `Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(600, 100, Color.TURQUOISE);` and `stage.setScene(new Scene(new Pane(rectangle, shape)));` for `stage.setScene(new Scene(new Pane(rectangle, text)));`. And I delete `Shape shape = Shape.subtract(rectangle, text);` and `shape.setFill(Color.TURQUOISE);`, so the result is the same.

Comment: @yoda666, the visual result is the same. But, as I explained in the answer, the difference is that the new `Shape` has exactly the same `Bounds` that the rectangle, while the `Text` does not. So now you do not have position the `Text` in the center of the `Rectangle`. Instead, yo only have to position the `Rectangle` and the `Shape` in the same position or you can bind the positions (e.g. you can bind `layoutX`, `layoutY`, `translateX`, `translateY`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a Text object, you can use a [Label](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Label.html) with its [alignment](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#alignmentProperty) set to center the text.  Then you just need to force the Label’s minimum width to match the parent’s width (which is, roughly, mimicking what some layouts do):

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    var rectangle = new Rectangle(600, 100, Color.TURQUOISE);
    var text = new Label("TEXT");
    text.setFont(new Font(100));
    text.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    Pane pane = new Pane(rectangle, text);
    text.minWidthProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty());
    text.minHeightProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty());
    stage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, vertical alignment doesn't work. I tried to add `text.minHeightProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty());` and `text.setPadding(new Insets(0));`, but it has no effect. What's the problem, please?

Comment: It doesn’t?  It seems to work for me, with or without setting the insets.  Is the text always top-aligned?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. `setAlignment` has an effect only on horizontal alignment. The text is always vertically in the middle, but the window doesn’t have a height of 100, but 185.

Comment: Are you saying that the vertical centering appears to be visually correct to the eye, but the numbers don’t seem correct?

Comment: Yes, the text is vertically centered. However, not in the center of the rectangle, but in the center of the window, which has a height of 185. Although, it's probably because the text has a height of 146.

Comment: I think I understand now.  You want the text centered based on its exact *visual bounds.*  Be aware that `new Font(100)` doesn’t mean text has a height of 100 pixels.  It creates a font whose characters are 100 *points* high.  A point is ¹⁄₇₂ of an inch, so a 100-point font will have characters which are 100÷72≈1.39 inches high.  The exact number pixels needed to display text of that height will depend on the dot pitch of the monitor on which the program runs.

Comment: Sorry. This is a problem that images cannot be inserted into comments. Yes, I know that the font size isn't in pixels, but the picture in question shows that a font with a size of 100 is far from 100 pixels high. So the match between the font size and the height of the rectangle is purely random. So why is the height 146 when the text itself is about 70 pixels high?

Comment: Probably due to font ascent and descent.  If you want your text positioned based strictly on its outline, I think Slaw’s answer is what you want.

Comment: Yes. Even so thank you. This works correctly with a smaller font size.